# Does Only Taylor Series Solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

the series I'm stressing on is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\frac{\sin(e^{-n})}{n}
$$

What other ways can we prove its convergence or is Taylor Series only way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $(\forall x\in[0,\infty)):\sin(x)\leqslant x$ and therefore $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\sin(e^{-n})\leqslant e^{-n}$.